# Android emulator looks bad on retina display (pixelated)

Tags: android, retina-display

All my emulations have pixelated text and images like this on retina display. I've tried adjusting numerous setting to no avail. Does anyone know a solution to get it crystal clear?

[image: Nexus 4 screenshot from Macbook Pro Retina]

Here are the settings I've tried using:
[image: Nexus 4 Settings]

And...
[image: Nexus 5 Settings]

Note that use Host GPU is checked for both.

Comment: What settings are you using for the emulator (both what hasn't worked previously and what you're using in the image above)?

Comment: @Brett Added some images of the settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welp, figured out my own problem. Switching from Host GPU to Snapshot fixes it! Hope this helps someone.

Comment: How do you switched it?

Comment: Go to advanced settings in emulator and change it ,
Advanced settings--> Emulated Performance-->Graphics --> Switch to Hardware or software

Comment: emulator version 31.2.10-8420304. ubuntu 1804 this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

## Windows 10 Solution

I ran into the same issue with Windows 10 and a high-dpi screen.

The problem is that Windows by default scales any application for backwards compatiblity, i.e. to not make it appear tiny and hard to use.

To disable scaling, open the emulator application's **properties** (right-click icon, then right-click emulator-x86.exe). There, under the tab **compatibility**, check "**disable display scaling on high DPI settings**".

(Screenshot is in German, but the gist should be clear...)

[image: Screenshot of check to disable high DPI scaling]

Comment: As for 2022, please refer below url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985854/android-emulator-looks-pixelated

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we have 1920x1080 OS display resolution device, then
choose Nexus 5X, with 1920x1080 resolution that is identical to your OS display resolution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9igrS.png)