# Android Emulator looks pixelated

Tags: android, android-emulator

Yesterday, I updated my android studio and downloaded updated SDK's.

Since then my emulator looks very pixelated and if any text is small it's hardly readable.

[image: emulator]

**Emulator config:**

- Nexus 5
- Android 6.0 x86_64 google apis
- not using host GPU emulation

**PC config:**

- 8 GB RAM
- Core i3 4130 CPU
- integrated graphics (useless)
- Windows 7 enterprise 64 bit

If anyone have experience with a similar issue please help.

I tried lowering the resolution of the emulator with no avail.

**Note:** I can not use third party emulators due to restrictions from infosec department.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira windows 7 enterprise 64 bit

Comment: you must to update graphics driver in your system.

Comment: try changing your emulator dpi with adb

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira how to change dpi? I tried changing resolution and had same results.

Comment: Can we do anything for ubuntu. I can't perfeclty see the design in emulator just like my designers do in there MAC

Answer (score 5):

Disable display scaling on Windows 10:

1. Right-click on the emulator icon in the taskbar.
2. Right-click on qemu-system-x86_64.exe:
   [image: popup menu]
3. Select 'Properties' in another menu that appears:
   [image: another menu]
4. Switch to Compatibility tab and click 'Change high DPI settings' button:
   [image: Properties dialog]
5. Check 'Override high DPI scaling behavior'.
6. Set 'Scaling performed by' to 'Application':
   [image]

Comment: FInally! It works

Comment: not working windows 11

Comment: Not working windows 10

Comment: How do I fix this for Mac (OSX)?

Comment: @fahmy I suggest asking a separate question. You can link it here.