# Is it possibile to obtain better graphic quality on Android Studio using Flutter (bad antialias)?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

When I test my Flutter app (default font) using Android Studio on Windows I see bad quality characters (chars with bad antialias). When I run the app on a phone the antialias is perfect (so it is not a debug mode problem). Is there a way to obtain the same good quality in the emulator on PC?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a common problem found on Android Emulators running on a windows machine.

I had a similar problem with a Windows Laptop of mine and solved it following [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32985854/android-emulator-looks-pixelated).

It should work even if you are using windows 11

Comment: That's the issue but the fix suggested in the linked page doesn't resolve in my Win10 :(